# Message passing with observable doesn't work

Tags: angular

Well here is a plnk, http://plnkr.co/edit/y7PZONWELeG4f2Ywbw4k.

```
@Injectable()
export class MsgService{
// First solution sends nothing to the console in ChatList
private msgSource = new Subject<string>()

msgEvent$ = this.msgSource.asObservable()

// Second solution -> sends 'completed' in the ChatList comp
//chat_id;
//msg = Observable.of(this.chat_id)

sendMsg(id){
  this.msgSource.next(id)
  //this.chat_id = id
}}
```

I am trying to to pass a message from child to parent via service with observable, but it doesn't work. Here is example at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html (Parent and children communicate via a service). I have 2 solutions - first give no clue at all, nothing passed to console, second - gives subscription completed but i didn't send any complete() messages. So what the problem with this ?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to share a service between components, then only provide it on a common ancestor but not on every component where you want to inject it.

At every place where you add it to `providers: [MsgService]` a new **different** instance is created, but you need a shared one.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'messages',
  template: `<div>Message from {{id}} chat</div>`
  //providers: [MsgService]
})

export class Chat{
```